# Unable to unmarshal json to protobuf struct field

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers

I have a proto file similar to this.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package proto;
import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";


message JobCreateRequest {
    string Name = 1 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "name", (gogoproto.moretags)= "validate:\"required,max=100\""];
    string Description = 2 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "description", (gogoproto.moretags) = "validate:\"required,max=100\""];
    google.protobuf.Value Data = 3 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "data", (gogoproto.moretags) = "validate:\"required\""];
}
```

I am trying to unmarshal below json into protobuf using "encoding/json" library:

```
{
 "name": "India",
 "description": "test job",
 "data": { 
    "id": 1 
  }
}
```

The code to decode request json to protobuf is:

```
json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(req)
```

But the resulting Data field inside JobCreateRequest struct is always set to **nil**. What is the right way to use struct Value in protobuf?

Answer (score 11):

If you use [google.golang.org/protobuf](https://google.golang.org/protobuf), then you can use `google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson` to convert.

```
req := &proto.JobCreateRequest{}
err := protojson.Unmarshal(bytes, req)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb) to convert JSON to protobuf.

```
req := proto.JobCreateRequest{}
jsonpb.Unmarshal(r.Body, &req)
```

Comment: since Saurav is using gogo proto, you probably want gogo's version of jsonpb which I think is slightly different: https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/jsonpb/jsonpb.go