# "no default signer setup" error when invoking transaction using Idemix credential

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to setup Idemix based on the following documentation that I found:

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/idemix.html
- https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#getting-idemix-cri-certificate-revocation-information
- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/idemixgen.html

But when invoking a transaction, i received the error below:

```
$ docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPTYPE=idemix" -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1IdemixMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com" cli peer chaincode query -C channel1 -n chaincode1 -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
Error: error getting default signer: error obtaining the default signing identity: no default signer setup
```

Steps that I took:

1. Register a user `User1@org1.example.com` to fabric CA `fabric-ca-client register --id.name User1@org1.example.com --id.secret mysecret --id.type client --id.affiliation org1 --id.attrs role=2 -u http://localhost:7054`
2. Enroll the user and created an idemix identity `fabric-ca-client enroll --enrollment.type idemix -u http://User1@org1.example.com:mysecret@localhost:7054`
3. Rename `$USER1_DIR/msp/IssuerRevocationPublicKey` to `$USER1_DIR/msp/RevocationPublicKey`. During transaction invocation, the name `RevocationPublicKey` is expected, not `IssuerRevocationPublicKey`
4. Prepare the idemix msp. I copied `IssuerPublicKey` and `IssuerRevocationPublicKey` of the CA to the `msp` folder. I need to rename `IssuerRevocationPublicKey` to `RevocationPublicKey` else `configtxgen` will complain
5. In `configtx.yaml`, add an Idemix MSP

   ```
   - &Org1Idemix
       Name: Org1IdemixMSP

       # ID to load the MSP definition as
       ID: Org1IdemixMSP

       msptype: idemix
       MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1idemix.example.com/

       Policies: &Org1IdemixMSPPolicies
           Readers:
               Type: Signature
               Rule: "OR('Org1IdemixMSP.member')"
           Writers:
               Type: Signature
               Rule: "OR('Org1IdemixMSP.member')"
           Admins:
               Type: Signature
               Rule: "OR('Org1IdemixMSP.admin')"
   ```
6. Create genesis block, channel block, start network etc2 (as usual)
7. Try to query transaction and the aforementioned error appears

I did some troubleshooting and based on `idemixgen` documentation, I found out that I need to put a default signer into the idemix msp i.e. in the `user` folder. So I placed `User1@org1.example.com`'s `SignerConfig` file into the `user` folder and rerun `configtxgen`. I received the following error:

```
Error loading MSP configuration for org: Org1IdemixMSP: unexpected EOF
```

Next I did some comparing with the `SignerConfig` generated by `idemixgen` and `SignerConfig` of `User1@org1.example.com`. The one generated by `idemixgen` cannot be opened while the other one is a .json file (shown below), so the format is different. Running `configtxgen` Using the SignerConfig generated by `idemixgen` is successful. I want to try to invoke transactions by identities generated by `idemixgen` but there is no way to generate an identity except for the default signer.

```
{
    "Cred": "CkQKIK/7Slvg7laNMv8n7urCKpRN4gTZJZ7xQUyqPQ0GskWFEiCq/aRBmXlQAnSeJLXViGEHLRoztSCoHU6PDXaft+STexJECiB1dosl0QwT5dR/iNwfj0UvWZLph5U6fTMUVjYXE3W/UhIg6U+q6S9xMZhL7SHYe/v//Vhsw7X7N+93Ha4qQiWu0OIaIKcFZamTWwD5VQppZDEdxv5nr4DZAOn/S0r3gchLFG66IiD7kc8IZFRji8ub7yS5ueK8ZcLm5o+WR9a7wAx7o6fKQCogieDBP6ZS9S2R/JDVaLcAcNbtGlnF2fRS37GyoZmxko4qIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACKiArm8Pnrt+hrBAk1PD9trARpE6XVbdfXN+27uSe9r8uxCogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE=",
    "Sk": "LwrgRX48aewbqKWrvNjo5VFfNSDIJAvdaR4brzOsnWM=",
    "organizational_unit_identifier": "org1",
    "enrollment_id": "User1@org1.example.com",
    "credential_revocation_information": "CAESiAEKIP4MM1C0yWwgKFYPV3wokTrOHFOaEr+EPNImFraJwJ77EiBOpmBXc4rAVNta4cY32BO5JN144ofQNYnSae00o35qKxogcCBG58VCo7N2dw11Ek4+Ue/LJHWNYVhI6Qm0gb7cJ/8iIAVU47zTiMKQQu6mSSl+sp+LTL6AghqYs+ASgRFKrQSbGmgwZgIxAJRyRpR+k3SaAVRm4GM3l+zBU6V/7g73C9RQIU9kPef9XqVl0Gb+hQqrgd1HsTQ5GgIxANb6XNB+CrrQgwbt6msa0SG+aQKpSl48EeP/V7beUkshNubudBS+WjS+PRbf5aW0Nw=="
}
```

Repo here: https://github.com/aldredb/idemix-sample

Answer (score 0):

I went deep with the code...
if you interested, you can find the GetIdemixMspConfig function in msp/configbuilder.go at fabric 1.4 release branch.
in this function, we can see it will attempt loading a signconf with proto type.
However, we enroll the msp with ca client cli and which returns us a json...
I searched some topic as [Unable to unmarshal json to protobuf struct field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955253/unable-to-unmarshal-json-to-protobuf-struct-field)

In my point of view, that proto Unmarshal will fail with json format.

Comment: @user1055010, ..., I had raised ticket to Fabric about the different format issue. If you still need it works, you can try to convert json file to proto format... :-)