# Unable to unmarshal json into protobuf message

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers

My problem is pretty much the opposite of this one: [Unable to unmarshal json to protobuf struct field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955253/unable-to-unmarshal-json-to-protobuf-struct-field)

I have a message with several nested messages of the following form:

```
message MyMsg {
  uint32 id = 1;
  message Attribute {
     ...
  }
  repeated Attribute attrs = 2;

  message OtherAttribute {
    ...
  }
  OtherAttribute oAttr = 3;
  ...
}
```

Some external dependencies will send this message JSON form, which needs to then be unmarshalled into a `go` struct. When trying to use [`jsonpb`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb) like so, where `resp` is a `*http.Response`:

```
msg := &MyMsg{}
jsonpb.Unmarshal(resp.Body, msg)
```

The message is not fully decoded into the struct, i.e. some of the nested structs are missing. When the message is however decoded simply using `encoding/json` like so:

```
msg := &MyMsg{}
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(msg)
```

All attributes are successfully decoded into the struct.

As `jsonpb` is the official package to (un)marshall between protobuf/json, I was wondering whether anyone has any idea as to why this type of behaviour could occur. Do the default behaviours for `jsonpb` and `encoding/json` differ in a way that would explain one being able to unmarshall and the other not? If so where would one configure the behaviour of `jsonpb` accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `encoding/json` is the following:

1. Unknown fields are allowed, i.e. in case of a field not matching it is simply ignored without an error being raised.
2. Before it is ignored, the Decoder attempts to match the field without case sensitivity

The behaviour in point 1 can be replicated in `jsonpb` by using the [`Unmarshaller`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb#Unmarshaler) struct and setting the property `AllowUnknownFields` to `true`

```
var umrsh = jsonpb.Unmarshaler{}
umrsh.AllowUnknownFields = true
msg := &MyMsg{}
umrsh.Unmarshal(resp.Body, msg)
```

It does not seem to be possible to replicate the behaviour from point 2 within `jsonpb`.